# cannot execute binary file: Exec format error But i was able to before update

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, arm

I was trying to run a binary on my raspberry, called [mapshot](https://github.com/Palats/mapshot) but the code had some issues.
I created a new issue and the code owner fixed it.

During that time i was configuring my raspian server and also run `apt-get update` and other things, then I saw he fixed the code and i was trying to run it again(v13).
Then I got an error `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. I was thinking maybe he messed something up, so i was trying the older version v12. But I started to get the same issue.

I googled up, then I saw, the file is:
`mapshot-linux13: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, Go BuildID=uddLtPxdcvoAGXUXjLzN/18KPkQR-w3AkfEdyv7ZO/8woBqF8KCDZW7lw-YD2O/r5WVmHnTYn0RB8KU0AgZ, not stripped`

and my system architecure is ARM:

```
mapshot@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4
...
```

Which is completetly make sense, but then how was I able to run it before without any issue? I was getting the error from the script, i was able to run with the `--help` command..etc

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running an emulator (such as qemu) it will not be possible to run the binary (not a script).

What is possible is that you built your own version of 0.12 using configure, make, make install. Or downloaded a binary that someone else created that way (which is a bad idea).

Comment: I know, it totally makes sense, that now it doesn't want to work. But I'm certain that it was working before...

Comment: How did you get the previous binary?

Comment: From the repo, with a normal wget nothing else, I watched back on my bash history